# Autofilter with 2 criteria in same column using <>

Tags: excel, vba, autofilter

I am trying to filter out 2 strings of text on the same column but cannot find the correct syntax.

I saw some other examples were I would use an array of acceptable values but I cannot use that in my scenario as new values are added regularly and it wouldn't be practical. The ones that I am filtering out are always there and I don't want those in my final result.

Here is what I have tried:

```
    ActiveSheet.Range("$a$10:$bv$500").AutoFilter Field:=51, Criteria1:="=<>Sent to UW Final" _
    , Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="=<>Pending Cancellation"

    ActiveSheet.Range("$a$10:$bv$500").AutoFilter Field:=51, Criteria1:="<>" & "Sent to UW Final" _
    , Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="<>" & "Pending Cancellation"

    ActiveSheet.Range("$a$10:$bv$500").AutoFilter Field:=51, Criteria1:=Array("=<>Sent to UW Final" _
    , "=<>Pending Cancellation"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

Comment: The first attempt above will work by using `xlAnd` instead of `xlOr`. This is a great exercise in using the macro recorder to check for syntax when doing a manual unit test.

Comment: I have tried xlAnd on the 1st and 2nd ones and neither one worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a **single column** example that uses `AND` rather than `OR`:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("$G$1:$G$23").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:= "<>Sent to UW Final", Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<>Pending Cancellation"
```

You can adapt a similar syntax to your table.

**EDIT#1:**

Before:

[image]

The code:

```
Sub filterrr()
    ActiveSheet.Range("$G$1:$G$23").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>Sent to UW Final", Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<>Pending Cancellation"
End Sub
```

and after:

[image]

Comment: This does not work, It is very similiar to what I have already tried.

Comment: @MEC  see my **EDIT#1** .........................can you replicate it on a clean worksheet

Comment: Your answer worked, I just had to move the order of my filters, I moved the filter you wrote to the end of all the other filters and it worked, thanks.

Comment: @MEC  Good Job! .......................as you see, applying multiple filters can be very tricky since they can affect each other.